# compare function giving segmentation fault in qsort

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, compare, qsort

I did a compare function for qsort and it causes a segmentation fault.
why is this happening and how to fix it?

```
example my two arrays are:
G->grades = [2,3,3,2,2,2] 
G->order =  [0,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to sort G->order using G->grades values. So the output should be:
 `G->order = [2,3,0,4,5,6]`

```c
u32* vert_grades;

char OrdenWelshPowell(Grafostv* G)
{
    vert_grades = G->grades;
    qsort(G->order, G->n, sizeof(u32), comp_grades);
    return 0;
}

int comp_grades(const void *v1, const void *v2) {
    u32 degree1 = vert_grades[*(const u32 *)v1 - 1];
    u32 degree2 = vert_grades[*(const u32 *)v2 - 1];
    printf("degree2: %u\n", vert_grades[*(const u32 *)v2 - 1]);
    if (degree1 > degree2)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (degree1 < degree2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

pd: I dont care to order G->grades for the moment.

Comment: Which line is causing the segfault?

Comment: Hallo! Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. This should also show the `#include` files you are using, and the `struct` definitions.

Comment: Hi, I believe it can be this line:  
```c  
u32 degree2 = vert_grades[*(const u32 *)v2 - 1];
```
is it posible that ```-1```does something like ```vert_grades[-1]```  if ```*(const u32 *)v2 = 0```

Comment: You tell us what you put in that array: was it `0...` or `1...`? But the MCVE that readers can use to replicate the problem will show that.

Comment: @WeatherVane right away

Comment: Part of the idea of preparing the MCVE is that in doing so you might find the problem yourself. It's one of the tools in the debugging box.

Comment: This testcase gives segmentation fault, so I'm pretty sure is what I suspected, but how can I fix comp_grades function?  
spoiler: delete ```-1``` doesn't resolve it

Answer (score 1):

You have the array

```
G->order = [0,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Notice that your arrays have 6 elements, so the range of their indexing must be either `0..5` or `1..6`. Your `cmp` function presumes the latter, because it subtracts `1` from the index.

But the ordering array has the range `0..6` which does not suit either system. In this case the first value `0` will break the array bounds because you subtract `1`.

I suggest the initial data before sorting should be

```
G->order = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```